# how to get all the data files and its detailed information using postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

Currently, I need to analyze PostgreSQL and its file information. I know that there is a function: `pg_relation_filepath`, which can get the underlying location of a file. Then, I can get every information about this file, which is perfect.

However, I couldn't get every table name from PG. In detail, if I'm in database `A`, I can't see the table information in `B`. I knew that I could get the table list from `pg_tables`. But the real question is that I can't get a complete list since once I switched to another database, I can't see the table.

For instance, I query this one in database `A`:

```sql
select count(*) from pg_tables;
------
140
```

Then, I use `\c B` command to database `B`:

```sql
select count(*) from pg_tables;
------
138
```

Clearly, the result was different. I want to know if there is a way to query every database table name regardless of which database I am in.

Or, can I use a different way to get every database file information (Its size, location and name) using SQL?

Suggested that I have ultimate privilege in this whole system. Because I'm developing a new database system based on PG (database kernel development), so I can change everything inside the database system.

Comment: "*if there is a way to query every database table name regardless of which database I am in*" - no, there isn't. You need to connect to each database, then run your SQL query for every database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Okay， thank you. Do you think it's possible to get it done using a function within PG?